# RTTI support for C++11 ( _CPPRTTI and __GNUG__ )

Tags: c++, c++11, rtti

I am updating some old C++ code.

I've come across the following:

```
    #if defined( _CPPRTTI ) || defined( __GNUG__ )
            const char* default_name{ (typeid(FooClass)).name() };
    #else
            const char* default_name{ "unknown" };
    #endif
```

RTTI is Run-Time Type Information, it looks as though it is dealing with certain compilers that did't support typeid().

But this code is > 15 years old.

Can one assume that RTTI support is in place for C++11?

Comment: It's in place if you enable it.

Comment: Isn't the { } syntax C++11? How is it 15 years old in that case?

Comment: @Neil They said they're updating the code for C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some compilers allow you to disable support for RTTI at compile-time.  For example, see Visual C++'s [/GR-](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we6hfdy0.aspx) and GCC's [-fno-rtti](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html).

If you don't use RTTI in your program (`typeid`, `dynamic_cast`, etc.) then disabling RTTI at compile-time may substantially reduce the size of the final binary.